# firing a click event for a child control

Tags: jquery

My markup is the following :

```
<li><span>..</span>
   <input type="button" id="clickme" Value="click ME" />
</li>
```

My question is how can I fire the click event of the input child of li ( the button ) automaticaly using jquery

I don't want to access the button by its id I want to access it via .children() method.  I tried to do this but it didn't work :

```
<li id="liID"><span>...</span><input type="button" id="clickme" value="click ME" />

$("#liID").children("input").trigger('click');
```

but that didn't work :/

Comment: For your updated question that code should work as is, _and does_: http://jsfiddle.net/Ne33L/. But what do you expect to happen when the button is clicked? Do you have other code assigning a click handler for the button, or...? Can you provide a more complete demonstration at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('#clickme').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trigger()` method:

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
$('li input').trigger('click');
```

or:

```
$('#clickme').click()
```

close the `li` tag and try using `find()` method:

```
<li id="liID"><span>...</span><input type="button" id="clickme" value="click ME" /></li>
```

```
$("#liID").find("input").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
$('#clickme').click();
```

Which is a shortcut for:

```
$('#clickme').trigger('click');
```

For more information see the jQuery API doco for [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

**EDIT:** You seem to be saying you want to select the input via the parent li element's id. If so, do the following if you don't want to depend on the input being a direct child:

```
$("#liID").find("input").click();
// OR
$("#liID input").click();
```

Or if you only want to select inputs that are direct children your code should work:

```
$("#liID").children("input").trigger('click');
```

Comment: i don't want to access th button by it's id i want to access it via .children() method i tried to do this but it didn't work :

<li id="liID"><span>...</span><input type="button" id="clickme" value="click ME" />

$("#liID").children("input").trigger('click');

but that didn't work :/

Comment: That code should work for the html you've shown in your updated question, but I've updated my answer with a couple of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually trying to programatically click the button, or just to trigger some Javascript attached to its click event? The two are different:

To trigger some JS attached to the click event, you can simply do something like

```
$('input', '#liID').click();
$('#liID').children('input').trigger('click');
etc
```

However, to the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to actually fake a click event with JS. You can trigger the JS attached to the event handler, but if you're looking for the default functionality, I don't think there's any reliable way to do it, so you are best off creating a JS function and attaching it to the click event of the input. Then you can trigger that programatically.